# Relation between eigenvectors of $A$ and $\text{Exp}(At)$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is the following true?

> Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and suppose that $v(t)$ be a (continuous) eigenvector of $\text{Exp}(At)$ for all $t$.
>   Then $v(t)$ is equal to a constant vector $w$ if and only if $w$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

Of course, if $w$ is an eigenvector of $A$ then it is trivially an eigenvector of $\text{Exp}(At)$ as well.

What about the other direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $v(t)=w$. Since $v(t)$ is an eigenvector we have that

$$e^{At}v(t) = \lambda(t) v(t)$$

and take derivatives on both sides

$$Ae^{At}v(t) + e^{At}v'(t) = \lambda(t) v'(t) + \lambda'(t) v(t)$$

Now plug in $v'(t)=0$ then $v(t)=w$:

$$A\left(e^{At}v(t)\right) = \lambda'(t)v(t)$$

$$A(\lambda(t)v(t)) = \lambda'(t)v(t)$$

$$Aw = \frac{\lambda'(t)}{\lambda(t)}w$$

which is an eigenvalue equation for $w$ with $A$. One can go even farther by taking one more derivative and showing that

$$0 = \left(\frac{\lambda'(t)}{\lambda(t)}\right)'w \implies \frac{\lambda'(t)}{\lambda(t)} = k$$

for arbitrary $w\neq 0$. Thus $\lambda(t) = C \cdot e^{kt}$.

$\textbf{EDIT}$: By Severin's suggestion below, one might wonder if it is always well defined to divide by $\lambda(t)$. The determinant of $e^{At}$ is the product of its eigenvalues, but we have that

$$\det e^{At} = e^{t\cdot\text{tr} A} \neq 0$$

so $0$ cannot be an eigenvalue of $e^{At}$.

Comment: You are missing a derivative right before the implication arrow. Maybe you could also briefly say how to deal with $\lambda(t)=0$ (for all $t$). Nice answer anyway!

Comment: @SeverinSchraven thanks!

Comment: @SeverinSchraven $\lambda(t)=0$ is not possible because $\text{det}e^{At} = e^{t\cdot\text{tr}A} \neq 0$

Comment: I know why it is not possible :) I was more thinking of the OP. It would look pretty in the answer.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven ok I will add it

Comment: All OP said was that $v(t)$ was continuous. What if the derivative doesn't exist? Is there something in the hypotheses of the question that implies $v(t)$ has to be differentiable?

Comment: @colorlessgreenidea if we're assuming $v(t)$ is constant, then it is differentiable, even if we make its derivative $0$ later.